# How do i access the non-final variable number inside an inner class in Java?

Tags: java, android

This is my first time programming in Java so i can't understand why i can't access the variables outside of a function. I tried to change the variable to final but there's still an error:

> The final local variable number cannot be assigned, since it is
>   defined in an enclosing type

When there's no final keyword in the variable, the error is this:

> Cannot refer to a non-final variable number inside an inner class
>   defined in a different method

Here's my code:

```
        String[] number = this.nextNumber();
        Button submitbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        submitbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  // Perform action on clicks
                  //Toast.makeText(Addition.this, inp.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  if(inp.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                      Toast.makeText(Addition.this, "Please enter your answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  } else {
                      int answer = Integer.parseInt(inp.getText().toString());
                      if(Integer.parseInt(number[1]) == answer) {
                          Toast.makeText(Addition.this, "NICE!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          int currentPoint = Integer.parseInt((String) points.getText());
                          currentPoint = currentPoint + 1;
                          points.setText(Integer.toString(currentPoint));
                          number = Addition.this.nextNumber(); // this part doesn't work. why?
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Addition.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  }
              }
          });
```

I put a comment on the part that doesn't work. please tell me why

Answer (score 5):

Well, the two rules you're coming up against are exactly as the compiler states:

- A final variable has to be assigned exactly once - you can't change its value later
- You can *only* access local variables from an anonymous inner class if they're final

It's not clear what you're trying to do or *why* you're trying to change the value of the local variables from within your `OnClickListener`. What's the bigger picture here? Could you maybe declare a variable within the anonymous inner class itself, or make it an instance variable within your class?

If you're new to Java I would *strongly* advise you to write simpler code to start with. Anonymous inner classes are *relatively* advanced.

I'd actually encourage you to play with Java as a *language* on the desktop before starting Android development - play with the core libraries (collections, IO etc) and any interesting bits of the language within a simple console app which will be easy to start and debug without any Android-specific complications to hamper you.

Comment: i'm trying to reset the number when a button is clicked. is there any other way to change the value of the variable when my button is clicked?

Comment: @Kevin: But that's a *local* variable. What effect do you think changing it will have?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As Jon says using a listener to modify a local variable is no use, when the listener assigns it a value the local variable would have gone out of scope and not reachable by any other means. What I write below makes sense only if `number` has life outside of this method.

Inside the anonymous inner class you can only access `final` variables of the containing scope. But you cannot **assign** to final variables. The usual trick used is to use a final wrapper around a non-final variable. For example if `number` was a `String`, not an array (`String[]`) then the following will work:

```
   final String[] number = new String[] { this.nextNumber(); } 
           // number[0] has the number, number itself is final wrapper
   Button submitbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
   submitbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // Perform action on clicks
           //Toast.makeText(Addition.this, inp.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           if(inp.getText().toString().equals("")) {
               Toast.makeText(Addition.this, "Please enter your answer",              
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           } else {
               int answer = Integer.parseInt(inp.getText().toString());
               if(Integer.parseInt(number[1]) == answer) {
                   Toast.makeText(Addition.this, "NICE!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   int currentPoint = Integer.parseInt((String) points.getText());
                   currentPoint = currentPoint + 1;
                   points.setText(Integer.toString(currentPoint));
                   number[0] = Addition.this.nextNumber();
                   // number is final and cannot be assigned but number[0] can
               } else {
                   Toast.makeText(Addition.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }
          }
      });
```